# I have a treemap<Integer, Person> where the Integer is a unique attribute of each Person, I want to print the elements sorted by another attribute

Tags: java, sorting, tree, treemap, treeset

My `Person` class has an integer ID which is unique and which I used as key value for the `TreeMap`. However, the person class also has another attribute 'age' which is NOT unique to each person (duplicates exist). I want to print my treemap by order of age allowing duplicates.

I tried putting all entries in a new `Treemap` where the key is age and not ID, but the `treemap` would remove duplicates and that's what I don't want.

I read somewhere that I should use `Treemap<Integer, List<Person>)` where the integer would be age but I couldn't figure out how to add these elements and print them.

Note: Person does implement comparable and the `compareto` method works based on age.

Help please

Comment: Why do you want a map? why not a list and sort the Person-elements by age, then print?

Comment: user2873661, did you understand my `TreeMap<Integer, List<Person>>` solution?

Answer (score 2):

You can extract a `List` of the values (`Person` objects) from the map and then implement a custom (anonymous) comparator:

```
List<Person> list = new ArrayList<Person>(map.values());
Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<Person>() {
    public int compare(Person p1, Person p2) {
        return p1.getAge().compareTo(p2.getAge());
    }
});
```

As a result, the `list` will be sorted by `age`.

Comment: Can't think of a better pre-8 approach.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way to do it with Java 8 and the Stream API:

```
idMap.values()
     .stream()
     .sorted(Comparator.comparing(p -> p.age))
     .forEach(System.out::println);
```

And here's a solution using `Map<Integer, List<Person>>`:

```
Map<Integer, List<Person>> ageMap = new TreeMap<>();
for (Person p : idMap.values()) {
    if (!ageMap.containsKey(p.age))
        ageMap.put(p.age, new ArrayList<>());
    ageMap.get(p.age).add(p);
}
for (Integer age : ageMap.keySet()) {
    System.out.println("Person with age " + age + ":");
    for (Person p : ageMap.get(age))
        System.out.println("    " + p);
}
```

Comment: Java8 always gets a plus :-)